Pub-Sub can't acknowledge messages when working with Google Marketplace Saas Integration
I am currently working on Google Marketplace Saas integration .
On running integration tests , I'm getting a single event notification continuously and the message is not getting acknowledged .
I've provided the related code snippet below . What am I doing wrong ?
const { PubSub } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

const { authClient, getAccessToken } = require('../../services/googleAuthClient');

const axios = require('axios');


//project id
const projectId = 'your_project_id';

//create pubsub instance
const pubsub = new PubSub({
  projectId, // project id
  authClient // service account credentials
});

const subscriptionName = 'your_subscription_name';



async function listenForMessages(subscriptionName) {
  // Create subscription with adjusted flow control and acknowledgment deadline
  const subscription = pubsub.subscription(subscriptionName);
  // console.log(`Listening for messages on subscription: ${subscriptionName}`, subscription);

  // Create message handler
  const messageHandler = async (message) => {
    console.log(`Received message ${message.id}`);
    console.log(`Data: ${message.data}`);
    console.log(`Attributes: ${JSON.stringify(message.attributes)}`);

    // Parse the message data
    const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message.data);
    const eventType = parsedMessage.eventType;
    const { eventId } = parsedMessage;

    // Debounce check to avoid processing the same message multiple times
    if (processedMessages.has(eventId)) {
      console.log(`Skipping already processed message with eventId: ${eventId}`);
      try {
        await message.ackWithResponse();
        console.log(`Ack for message ${message.id} successful.`);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Ack for message ${message.id} failed with error: ${e.errorCode}`);
      }
      return;
    }

    try {
      // Mark the event as processed
      processedMessages.add(eventId);

      // Handle the event based on eventType
      await handleEvent(eventType, parsedMessage);

      // Acknowledge the message immediately after processing
      try {
        await message.ackWithResponse();
        console.log(`Ack for message ${message.id} successful.`);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Ack for message ${message.id} failed with error: ${e.errorCode}`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Failed to process message ${message.id}:`, error);
      // Optionally nack the message if processing failed and you want to retry
      // message.nack();
    } finally {
      // Clean up the processed message after a delay
      setTimeout(() => {
        processedMessages.delete(eventId);
      }, 60000); // 60 seconds, adjust as needed
    }
  };

  // Start listening for messages
  subscription.on('message', messageHandler);
}

// Call the function to start listening for messages indefinitely
listenForMessages(subscriptionName);


async function handleEvent(eventType, parsedMessage) {
  console.log('eventType:', eventType);
  console.log('parsedMessage:', parsedMessage);
  const { eventId } = parsedMessage;

  // Debounce check
  // if (processedMessages.has(eventId)) {
  //   console.log(`Skipping already processed message with eventId: ${eventId}`);
  //   return;
  // }

  try {
    // Mark the event as processed
    processedMessages.add(eventId);

    // Switch-case to handle different event types
    switch (eventType) {
      // case 'ACCOUNT_ACTIVE':
      //   await handleAccountActive(parsedMessage);
      //   break;
      case 'ACCOUNT_DELETED':
        await handleAccountDeleted(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_CREATION_REQUESTED':
        await handleEntitlementCreationRequested(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_OFFER_ACCEPTED':
        await handleEntitlementOfferAccepted(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_ACTIVE':
        await handleEntitlementActive(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_PLAN_CHANGE_REQUESTED':
        await handleEntitlementPlanChangeRequested(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_PLAN_CHANGED':
        await handleEntitlementPlanChanged(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_PLAN_CHANGE_CANCELLED':
        await handleEntitlementPlanChangeCancelled(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_PENDING_CANCELLATION':
        await handleEntitlementPendingCancellation(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_CANCELLATION_REVERTED':
        await handleEntitlementCancellationReverted(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_CANCELLED':
        await handleEntitlementCancelled(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_CANCELLING':
        await handleEntitlementCancelling(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_RENEWED':
        await handleEntitlementRenewed(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_OFFER_ENDED':
        await handleEntitlementOfferEnded(parsedMessage);
        break;
      case 'ENTITLEMENT_DELETED':
        await handleEntitlementDeleted(parsedMessage);
        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Unknown event type: ${eventType}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling event:', error);
  } finally {
    // Remove the eventId from the processed set after a delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      processedMessages.delete(eventId);
    }, 60000); // 60 seconds, adjust as needed
  }
}



Followed Google Saas Integration docs .
Reference : https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/integrated-saas/backend-integration
